# Postgresql :joining on fields using CASE expression

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to join two tables on two fields with a below condition

```
If condition 1 is satisfied then join ON a.field_1 = b.field_1 
If condition 2 is satisfied then join ON a.field_2 = b.field_2
```

In order to do so, I am writing the below query

```
SELECT 
a.field_1,a.field_2,
b.field_1,b.field_2 FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
CASE WHEN COALESCE(TRIM(a.field_1),'') = '' THEN a.field_1 = b.field_1 
ELSE a.field_2 = b.field_2 END
```

I am not sure whether this would run.

Comment: Try it and you will know?

Comment: Since Postgres knows a Boolean data type, Boolean expression can evaluate to a Boolean value which itself is a Boolean expression and this should work out of the box (if you add the missing `ON` keyword).

Comment: Since you seem to be only caring if `a.field_1` is `NULL` why not `...CASE WHEN a.field_1 IS NULL THEN ...`? Though I'm not sure what that is going to get you as that would end up being `NULL = b.field_1` and that will resolve to `NULL`.  You need to provide an example with actual data to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html):

> T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 ON **boolean_expression**

A JOIN accepts an arbitrary "boolean expression", which may reference columns from both joined relations. While the trivial form is `t1.col = t2.col`, the boolean expression is not limited to it and so comparing two sets of columns based on some other column is totally fine.

Please note your syntax error `@sticky bit` pointed out.